# Associating timer with tables

Tags: java, timer

I am new to timer's and don't know much about them .My problem is i am creating 2 tables dynamically, and when ever a table is create a timer for 10 mins is assigned to it. I.e. the user has to fill that table in 10 mins else the table will be destroyed. I tried a making a small demo in which i print stuff 
The code is :

```
final Timer mytimers = new Timer(); 
Timer mytimers1 = new Timer();
 mytimers1 = new Timer();
final long delay1 = 5*1000; 
// mytimers = new Timer();
 mytimers.schedule(new TimerTask() {
Long current1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
 long check = current1;

      @Override
      public void run() {
        Long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(current);
        System.out.println("\n");

       if((current1 + delay1)<current)

       {        

       System.out.println("mytimmer is about to stop");

       mytimers.cancel();


       }


      }

    }, 100, 1000);





 mytimers1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        Long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("in" + current);


      }
    }, delay1, 1000);

    }
```

but when i tried implementing this int he final project it does not work as i have to make any variable inside the run a final , thus its value can not to be changed !!! 
Please let what should i do !!Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> ***i have to make any variable inside the run a final , thus its value can not to be changed!***

Either turn these variables into *member variables* or encapsulate these values in a proper class, instantiate the class and give a reference to that object to the timer task.

Even though the *reference* is final, the timer task will still be able to do things such as `myTableController.destroyTable()`.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this :

```
class YourClass{
Timer mytimers = new Timer(); 
Timer mytimers1 = new Timer();
long delay1 = 5*1000; 

mytimers.schedule(new TimerTask() {
Long current1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long check = current1;
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(current);
        System.out.println("\n");
       if((current1 + delay1)<current) {
       System.out.println("mytimmer is about to stop");
       mytimers.cancel();
       }
    }
}, 100, 1000);

mytimers1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        Long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("in" + current);
      }
    }, delay1, 1000);
    }
```

in your case you have created **anonymous 'concrete' class** ie TimerTask, and you are trying to access variables which are not in its scope.

So, if the variables you are trying to access are **local(method)** variables then they should be **declared final** or the other way around is to declare those variables as **instant(member)** variables that what i have done above.